# nmp install error, wanted to creat-react-app and got errror so i did

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install

I get :

```
throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\zur99\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)   
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []

**after doing npm install:**
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\js\package.json'
npm WARN js No description
npm WARN js No repository field.
npm WARN js No README data
npm WARN js No license field.
PS C:\js>
```

also, I don't have package.json anymore.

Comment: Why don't you have package.json anymore, Zur?

Comment: i dont know..
i did npm uninstall -g create-react-app
and that what happned...
also if i chack npm -v :
4.6.1
but when 

PS C:\js> npm install 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\js\package.json'
npm WARN js No description
npm WARN js No repository field.
npm WARN js No README data
npm WARN js No license field.